# Folder upload with blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, directory, blueimp

according to

[HTML5 drag and drop folder detection in firefox. Is it even possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423163/html5-drag-and-drop-folder-detection-in-firefox-is-it-even-possible/33431704#33431704)

and

[Does HTML5 allow drag-drop upload of folders or a folder tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590058/does-html5-allow-drag-drop-upload-of-folders-or-a-folder-tree)

up-to-date browser are capable to handle folder-upload properly.

When I tried to implement it, I got only file OR older upload capabilities, but I want to have it like Files and  - on drop-in - folders with their full structure (as Owncloud supports it with Chrome; and they rely on blueimp library as well).

I would also love to activate the support with recent firefox version.

Has somebody done something similar and some hints for me where to dig in?

I'm planning to contribute the outcome of this effort back to the library, so I'm very happy to collaborate :)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757322/cannot-get-dropped-folder-information-in-firefox-48

Answer (score 1):

Folder upload is entirely dependent on browsers supporting it.

As of November 2016, these browsers support folder upload:

- Chrome
- Opera
- Firefox
- Microsoft Edge

These browsers do not support folder upload:

- Safari
- Internet Explorer (all versions)

Presumably the Safari team will implement browser upload at some point in the near future because all its competitors have. It's a useful feature as an increasing quantity of files are being uploaded to the cloud.

Internet Explorer will probably never have folder upload because Microsoft is focussed on their modern Edge browser.

Notes:

- Chrome was the first major browser to support folder upload. It published code snippets here: https://developers.google.com/web/updatesa/2012/07/Drag-and-drop-a-folder-onto-Chrome-now-available
- Firefox 50 was the first version of Firefox to support folder upload (released on 15 November 2016). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/50
- Microsoft Edge has documented its folder upload support and API calls, here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/dev-guide/html5/folder-upload/