# Cannot get dropped folder information in FIrefox 48

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop

I cannot get dropped folder information, in Firefox 48, Windows 10.
`event.dataTransfer.files.length` is 0, when I drop folder.
It works fine when I drop file.

If you know a recommended method to get dropped folder information, I wish to know it.

You can reproduce it in https://jsfiddle.net/0GiS0/4ZYq3/.

Comment: Do not believe this is possible using `.dataTransfer.files` or `.dataTransfer.getFilesAndDirectories()`, though should be possible using `<input type="file">` element with `allowdirs` attribute set at `html`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did it with `<input type="file" allowdirs="allowdirs">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in Firefox 50.

See: [How to upload and list directories at firefox and chrome/chromium using change and drop events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664662/how-to-upload-and-list-directories-at-firefox-and-chrome-chromium-using-change-a)

> This was **fixed** with Firefox 50, which added [`webkitGetAsEntry`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/webkitGetAsEntry) support ([changelog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/50#drag_and_drop_api)).