# How to detect when an empty directory is being uploaded in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I created an input element with type="file", with multiple, webkitdirectory, allowdirs and directory attributes present.

I then added a "change" event handler, and it works when I select a directory of files to upload.

However, if I accidentally select an empty directory, I don't get the change event. Is there any other event I can use to detect that an empty directory has been chosen?

I'd like to be able to tell the user that the directory chosen is empty and to try to pick another one. Right now I have no way of detecting the user has done anything at all, and the user is given no indication of why their choice isn't doing anything.

This has been reported as a bug:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360412

but I'd like to know if there's a workaround.

Comment: Why do you have both `multiple` and directory attributes set? See [How to upload and list directories at firefox and chrome/chromium using change and drop events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664662/how-to-upload-and-list-directories-at-firefox-and-chrome-chromium-using-change-a)

Answer (score 0):

You can  iterate `Directory` and `File` instances at `drop` event using `Promise` constructor, scheduling function to call itself, push `File` instances to an array; if array `.length` is equal to `0` at completion of process, folder does not contain files.

See also [How to upload and list directories at firefox and chrome/chromium using change and drop events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664662/how-to-upload-and-list-directories-at-firefox-and-chrome-chromium-using-change-a).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    input[type="file"] {
      width: 98%;
      height: 180px;
    }

    label[for="file"] {
      width: 98%;
      height: 180px;
    }

    .area {
      display: block;
      border: 5px dotted #ccc;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .area:after {
      display: block;
      border: none;
      white-space: pre;
      content: "Drop your files or folders here!\aOr click to select files folders";
      position: relative;
      left: 0%;
      top: -75px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .drag {
      border: 5px dotted green;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    #result ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #result ul li {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #result li span {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: navy;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <label id="dropArea" class="area">
    <input id="file" type="file" directory allowdirs webkitdirectory/>
  </label>
  <output id="result">
    <ul></ul>
  </output>
  <script>
    var dropArea = document.getElementById("dropArea");
    var output = document.getElementById("result");
    var ul = output.querySelector("ul");

    function dragHandler(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      dropArea.className = "area drag";
    }

    function filesDroped(event) {
      var webkitResult = [];
      var files;
      console.log(event);
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      dropArea.className = "area";

      function handleEntries(entry) {
        let file = "webkitGetAsEntry" in entry ? entry.webkitGetAsEntry() : entry
        return Promise.resolve(file);
      }

      function handleFile(entry) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
          if (entry.isFile) {
            entry.file(function(file) {
              listFile(file, entry.fullPath).then(resolve)
            })
          } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
            var reader = entry.createReader();
            reader.readEntries(webkitReadDirectories.bind(null, entry, handleFile, resolve))
          } else {
            var entries = [entry];
            return entries.reduce(function(promise, file) {
                return promise.then(function() {
                  return listDirectory(file)
                })
              }, Promise.resolve())
              .then(function() {
                return Promise.all(entries.map(function(file) {
                  return listFile(file)
                })).then(resolve)
              })
          }
        })

        function webkitReadDirectories(entry, callback, resolve, entries) {
          console.log(entries);
          return listDirectory(entry).then(function(currentDirectory) {
            console.log(`iterating ${currentDirectory.name} directory`, entry);
            return entries.reduce(function(promise, directory) {
              return promise.then(function() {
                return callback(directory)
              });
            }, Promise.resolve())
          }).then(resolve);
        }

      }
      
      function listDirectory(entry) {
        console.log(entry);
        var path = (entry.fullPath || entry.webkitRelativePath.slice(0, entry.webkitRelativePath.lastIndexOf("/")));
        var cname = path.split("/").filter(Boolean).join("-");
        console.log("cname", cname)

        return Promise.resolve(entry);
      }
       // TODO: handle mozilla files
      function listFile(file, path) {
        path = path || file.webkitRelativePath || "/" + file.name;

        console.log(`reading ${file.name}, size: ${file.size}, path:${path}`);
        webkitResult.push(file);
        return Promise.resolve(webkitResult)
      };

      function processFiles(files) {
        Promise.all([].map.call(files, function(file, index) {
            return handleEntries(file, index).then(handleFile)
          }))
          .then(function() {
            console.log("complete", webkitResult);
            if (webkitResult.length === 0) {
              alert("empty directory")
            }
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            alert(err.message);
          })
      }

      // do webkit stuff
      if (event.type === "drop" && event.target.webkitdirectory) {
        files = event.dataTransfer.items || event.dataTransfer.files;
      } else if (event.type === "change") {
        files = event.target.files;
      }

      if (files) {
        processFiles(files)
      }

    }
    dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", dragHandler);
    dropArea.addEventListener("change", filesDroped);
    dropArea.addEventListener("drop", filesDroped);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```