# Handle directory/files upload with one input tag javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know if I could upload both file and folder in the same `<input>` tag. I've made it by drag-drop. But I want to do it by selecting files

In chrome, this allows me to select one folder.

```
<input class="input-button" type="file" multiple="multiple" webkitdirectory="" directory=""></input>
```

This allows me to select mutiples file but not folder

```
<input class="input-button" type="file" multiple="multiple" ></input>
```

How could I select both folder and files? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

No. Not at chrome, chromium. firefox provides two separate `<input>` element where `allowdirs` attribute is set, chrome, chromium do not. You can use two separate `<input>` elements. One with `multiple` attribute set, one with `webkitdirectory` and `allowdirs` set.

Comment: @ysfseu See also [How to upload and list directories at firefox and chrome/chromium using change and drop events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664662/how-to-upload-and-list-directories-at-firefox-and-chrome-chromium-using-change-a)