# How to allow the user to pick any file or directory in an <input type="file"> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

By creating an input tag such as:

```
<input type="file">
```

The user isn't able to select directories. By enabling certain flags:

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory multiple>
```

The user can now pick any directory, but not single files.

Is there any way to enable both?

Answer (score 6):

**You can only enable one of the two.**

```
<input type="file" id="myFiles" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory multiple>
```

The only way to select both files and directories using 'standard' ways is by providing two separate `input` elements.

Anyway, when you select a directory the files are available through the `DOM object` using `document.getElementById('myFiles')`.

Answer (score 2):

For now this is not possible.

There are several requests open for [mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=846931) and [chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=59818), you might want to keep up with them.

Comment: The **Firefox** issue is closed, but it still doesn't work (they marked it as duplicate of a bug to implement a new file API, but that doesn't provide the needed functionality). The **Chromium** issue mentiones that GTK does not provide a file dialogue to pick multiple folders, and that Windows doesn't either.

Answer (score 1):

Note, at firefox the attribute to allow directory upload is `allowdirs`, not `mozdirectory`.

firefox renders two `<input type="file">` elements when `allowdirs` attribute is set, one for file upload, one for directory upload; chromium does not.

One workaround is to utilize drag and drop to read either individual files, multiple files, directory or multiple directories.

Another workaround would be to include two `<input type="file">` elements; one having `webkitdirectory`, another having `multiple` attribute set.

See [How to upload and list directories at firefox and chrome/chromium using change and drop events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664662/how-to-upload-and-list-directories-at-firefox-and-chrome-chromium-using-change-a) for implementation which processes single file, multiple files, single directory, or multiple directory upload.

Comment: Do you have a reference or example for `allowdirs`? I could not find anything about it, and it doesn't seem to work in Firefox 101 on Linux.

Comment: The reason `allowdirs` is not working: It was removed in Firefox 101, and was an off-by-default setting before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664662/how-to-upload-and-list-directories-at-firefox-and-chrome-chromium-using-change-a#comment128710754_39665386