# Input type file directory multiple

Tags: html, file-upload

I'm using input like this:

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" webkitdirectory directory multiple>
```

It allows to select whole directory for some browsers.

Is it possible to select multiple directories?

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible, because the file selection window is controlled by the operating system.
One solution to this problem can be the creation of several multiple upload fields.

Comment: Is it an OS-specific restriction, or something in the HTML spec? If it's not in the spec, is there an OS that supports selecting multiple directories?

Comment: I found more details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633306/how-to-allow-the-user-to-pick-any-file-or-directory-in-an-input-type-file-ta/42633385#42633385