# Is it possible to select multiple directories with html input and webkitdirectory?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I have this input where users can choose a folder containing files to upload. Is there a way that I can allow users to select multiple folders at once?

```html
 <input
                type="file"
                name="upload_files[]"
                directory=""
                webkitdirectory=""
                multiple=""
                onChange={handleImageChange}
                style={{
                  marginTop: '12px',
                  marginBottom: '12px',
                }}
              />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530674/input-type-file-directory-multiple), it is not possible to select multiple folders at once.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633306/how-to-allow-the-user-to-pick-any-file-or-directory-in-an-input-type-file-ta