# Select multiple folders with html or JS

Tags: javascript, html, file

Is it possible to select multiple folders for uploading in single browse dialog with JS or html?
I need this case for real.

I'he tried something like this: `<input type="file" multiple directory />`
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Input type file directory multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530674/input-type-file-directory-multiple), it's impossible to create an input that can select multiple folders. You can create an input every time a folder is uploaded, and allow the users to continue to select & upload folders until they are done.