# <input type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple/> not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to setup a PWA that loads into an array the audio files from a specific folder of local file system. Using HTML `<input type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>` to pick the directory only allows to pick a single file if used on mobile device. On desktop it works fine instead. My mobile is an Android device with Chrome 92 installed. Anyone can help?

Comment: That would be because [it's simply not supported](https://caniuse.com/input-file-directory).

Comment: MDN says that it is supported since version 18 of Chrome on Android. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API And here: https://caniuse.com/?search=webkitdirectory

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633306/how-to-allow-the-user-to-pick-any-file-or-directory-in-an-input-type-file-ta