# Drag and drop or choose folder to upload in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Everybody know some library support drag and drop folder or open folder (like upload folder in Google Drive) then read all file in this folder to File in Angular 2?

Comment: A library is not necessary to achieve expected result. How is *oogle drive related to file upload?

Comment: @ guest271314 can you help me some example to read file in folder have been drop please? Thank you!

Comment: See [How to upload and list directories at firefox and chrome/chromium using change and drop events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664662/how-to-upload-and-list-directories-at-firefox-and-chrome-chromium-using-change-a)