# How to submit image input file with dropzone.js and php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a Wordpress website that users can submit posts from the front-end. Im trying to integrate dropzone.js so users can submit images via drag and drop and sort images from featured image and gallery images kinda like what craigslist has.

My question is how do I get the featured image to get added to a file input

```
<input id="fileUpload" type="file" name="feat-img" accept="image/*" value="">
```

and the gallery image get added to

```
<input id="gallery-photo-add" type="file" name="muti_files[]"  accept="image/*"  multiple>
```

Heres my code

Html

```
 <div class="dropzone" drop-zone="" id="file-dropzone"></div>
    <ul class="visualizacao sortable dropzone-previews" style="border:1px solid #000"></ul>
    <div class="preview" style="display:none;">
        <li>
            <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
            <img data-dz-thumbnail />
            <input id="fileUpload" type="file" name="feat-img" accept="image/*" value="">
            <input id="gallery-photo-add" type="file" name="muti_files[]"  accept="image/*"  multiple> 
            </div>
        </li>  
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.sortable').sortable();
    });
    $.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/min/dropzone.min.js',function(){         
          $('#file-dropzone').dropzone({ 
            url: "/",
            maxFilesize: 100,
            paramName: "uploadfile",
            maxThumbnailFilesize: 99999,
            previewsContainer: '.visualizacao', 
            previewTemplate : $('.preview').html(),
            init: function() {
              this.on('completemultiple', function(file, json) {

               $('.sortable').sortable('enable');

              });

              this.on('success', function(file, json) {
                alert('aa');
              });

              this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
                console.log('File1',file);
              });

              this.on('drop', function(file) {
                console.log('File2',file);
              }); 
            }
          });
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {});
</script>
```

PHP

```
if( ! empty( $_FILES ) ){
    $featured_image = $_FILES['feat-img'];
    $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $featured_image, $post_id);
    $files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
            $filee = array(
                'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
                'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
                'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
            );
            $_FILES = array("upload_attachment" => $filee);
            foreach ($_FILES as $filee => $array) {
                $newupload = my_handle_attachment($filee, $post_id);
            }
        }
    }
}
if ( ! empty( $_FILES['muti_files'] )  ) {
        $files = $_FILES['muti_files'];
        foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value){
            if ($files['name'][$key]){
                $file = array(
                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                );
            }
            $_FILES = array("muti_files" => $file);
            $i=1;
                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                      if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();
                        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
                        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
                        $attachment_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);
                        $vv .= $attachment_id . ",";
                        $i++;
                }
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_image_gallery',  $vv);
        }
    }
```

All this works fine if i dont use dropzone.js and just the `<input type="file">` here is a codepen so you can see what im trying to do https://codepen.io/T-SEA/pen/OdqQOw

Comment: _"My question is how do I get the featured image to get added to a file input"_ You can append multiple `File` objects to a single `FormData` instance. Not sure what the issues is?

Comment: Thats kinda my question. How do i append multiple files to a single FormData instance?

Comment: `const fd = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
 fd.append("file" + i, new File([i], 'file' + i, {type:"text/plain"}))
}

console.log([...fd.entries()])`

Comment: Where should this be placed?

Comment: You can create an HTML `<button>` or `<input type="submit">` element to `POST` the `FormData` to server when user completes procedure. See also [How to upload and list directories at firefox and chrome/chromium using change and drop events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664662/)