# How to retrieve the parent folder name with JavaScript or AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting file names with:

`<input type="file">`

For example, the path is:

`/folder/file.ext`

, and what needs to be extracted is:

`folder`

There is no much information about getting folder names with JavaScript or AngularJS

**Edit:**

The functionality is used by the admin to change or add new data

Comment: One way is to use `wekitdirectory` attribute to provide the user a means to select one or more folders, see [How to upload and list directories at firefox and chrome/chromium using change and drop events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664662/how-to-upload-and-list-directories-at-firefox-and-chrome-chromium-using-change-a)

Comment: @jsejcksn The accepted answer says that path names are not possible to obtain

Comment: @Studyland If this is just a website, then yes that is your answer.  However, if it is an electron application, or something similar, the answer changes.

Comment: @Studyland Why do you need to folder name? Are you developing locally?

Comment: @guest271314 the links to different files are organized in folders. Currently developing locally.

Comment: @Studyland Don't assume who downvotes your question.  Correlation is not causation.  Now, that aside, given this is for a website, it indeed not possible, as it would be a security breach if it was.  Secondly, votes are on content, not user.  This question shows poor research effort, lacks details, and is a duplicate of an existing question.  Just three reasons why someone might down vote a question.

Comment: @Studyland It would be more accurate to say I read the comments to understand the question; questions should be self contained, and comments can, and will be deleted at any time for any reason; they are not meant to store information that must be used to solve the question.

Comment: @Studyland If you use `webkitdirectory` on the `<input type="file">` attribute and select the parent folder you can read the folder. You can also use drag and drop to do the same thing when you drop a folder. Another way, on Chrome or Chromium-based browsers is to use `showDirectoryPicker()`.

Comment: Perhaps I was in a hurry when I posted this question. It could have been more elaborate, but sometimes the tiredness of coding is demotivating and writing more doesn't seem to be helpful. Thanks for the advices. I shall post my findings if I have a solution.

Comment: @guest271314, thanks I shall check the link and information