# Open random .html file when pressing Shuffle button

Tags: javascript, html, button, shuffle

My problem is that i have already made implementation of java script Shuffle button but only working in specific url which i will put into line **document.location.href** i used for this example somefile.html.

```
    jQuery('body').on('click', '#shuffle-button', function() {
        gtag('event', 'Shuffle', {
            'click': 'true'
        });
        ga('send', 'event', 'Shuffle', 'click', 'true');
        document.location.href = '**/somefile.html**';
    }).on('click', '#station-share-toggle, #station-share-close', function() {
        $('#station-share-buttons').toggle();
    }).on('click', '.jp-share-button', function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'), "share", "width=500, height=500");
        return false;
    });
```

So into same folder where is located **somefile.html** there is 350+ other .html files which i would like to make it when Shuffle button is clicked to transfer to random of that 350+ .html files.
This example only work for **somefile.html**. What i have to do to or where is my mistake I would be glad if someone has option to make it functional.

I found way to solve my problem I used the same line document.location.href = 'somefile.html' and in somefile.html when someone click then redirects the user (i.e., the web browser) to a random URL from a custom list of URLs.

Into file i used this lines:

```
<pre>
        var RedirectURLs = {
            "urls" : [
                { "url" : "http://www.example.com/1.html" },
                { "url" : "http://www.example.com/2.html" },
                { "url" : "http://www.example.com/3.html" }
            ]
        }
</pre>
```

The user is then automatically and randomly assigned to one of the URLs when the user visits this file. HTML file with JS. Thanks to all of you guys!

Comment: Based on this code, you're telling it to go to a really strangely (invalidly?) named file: `document.location.href = '**/somefile.html**'`. Nonetheless, why would you expect it to go anywhere other than that file based on the code you've written?

Comment: Aside from the unnecessary hinting asterisks, what have you tried to solve your issue?

Comment: Hi Marc, expect it to go anywhere other than that file based on the code thats why it's about random radio stations clients to shuffle if they want. And more of the radio stations i located into same folder with extention .html ex. radio1.html nameradio.html etc.. but is 350+ files, thats why im looking for random open .html files other than that file based on the code. Thank you for your reply i appreciate your time and help.

Comment: You can't inspect all files in a directory (as you could do in a serverside language like php). You could rename your htmls in a certain naming scheme like "station1.html"  - "station500.html" and fetch these files by changing the target URL based on a random number

Comment: _"You can't inspect all files in a directory (as you could do in a serverside language like php)."_ Yes, you can, with either `<input type="file" webkitdirectory>` [How to upload and list directories at firefox and chrome/chromium using change and drop events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39664662/) or WICG File System Access `window/showOpenDirectoryPicker()`.

Comment: @guest271314: that's not exactly the same as it requires a user action. So it is not really a workaround for fetching tasks.

Comment: It may also be a more promising approach to create a proper database or a data object (maybe stored as a JSON resource) than organizing you assets as a bunch of separate HTML files. There is also a good chance you can find an existing public station directory API (maybe REST based returning a JSON) that suits your requirements (including desired stations - maybe filter undesired ones)

Comment: @herrstrietzel There's ways around user action. Depends on how you want to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

> This example only work for somefile.html.

You'll have to refer to the same script and include the same HTML in your N HTML files.

Technically all of the files in the folder can be written to `navigator.strorage`, once, then the user doesn't have to request the files more than once when your Web page first runs - until they clear browsing data for that origin.

Then you can get the file(s) from `navigator.storage.getDirectory()` and render then in an `iframe` or separate `window` using a Blob URL, to avoid `location.href`, though that will work, too.